# How to determine basis and dimensions of subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm new into linear algebra and I encountered the following problem:

> In $\mathbb{R}^4$ we conside the following subspaces: $U=\{(x.y.z.w)\in \mathbb{R}^4 | x+y+z=0\}$, $V=\mathscr{L}((1,1,0,0), (2,-1,0,1),(4,1,0,1)).$
>
> 1. Determine the basis and dimensions of U, V and an algebraic representation of V.
> 2. Determine the basis and dimensions of $U \cap V$ and $U+V$.
> 3. Complete the base of $U \cap V$ in a base of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Firstly, I know that the subspace U is the set of solutions of the linear equation $x+y+z=0$ . But now I'm stuck as I have never seen such type of  problem and don't really understand what should I do.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zassenhaus_algorithm) might help!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just guess three linearly independent vectors contained in $U$.

Hint: $(1,-1,0,0) \in U$.

Note that $\dim U < 4$ - why?